# Is it possible to hack an Android App or an Android device without being root?

Tags: android

Simple question, as the title said.

I wondering if in an ideal world where rooting Android devices is not feasible mobile pen testing would be still possible or not.

Most of the sensitive folders will be inaccessible, right?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to iOS. Android is an open source OS from google and thus it and every app within the OS can be 'hacked' or at least its data accessed.

Comment: @MatthewPeters How does open source effect native vulnerabilities in an OS?  Normally rooting a device requires a hack without being root.  So I think the answer to the question is yes.

Comment: What you describe is a world where privilege escalation vulnerabilities do not exist within the operating system. While it is in theory possible, in practice it is extremely infeasible to achieve. Even if that was achieved however, many other exploits are still possible at the application level (and some at the OS level) which do not require privilege escalation at the OS level. These, however, are still dependent upon design or implementation flaws within the OS and/or application. In a "perfect world" similar to what you describe, these would not exist either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Much of android malware applications simply abuse the api and claim to do one thing (eg an innocent game) but then do malicious activities (subscribe to premium sms, without root).

Any application that makes use of WebViews and allow for javascript execution open themselves up to standard javascript attacks(XSS). In fact recently [a vulnerability](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2014/09/15/major-android-bug-is-a-privacy-disaster-cve-2014-6041) was disclosed in the old browser application somewhat related to this. This was also without root.

Man in the middle attacks can be done simply by connecting to an insecure wifi hotspot, without root(from the victim's perspective).

Applications that don't authenticate with their back end APIs and servers can be subject to a number of sniffing/spoofing related attacks, without root.

So yes, root is not needed in all malicious attacks on android.